# Create Buttons from image in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I've got this interesting challenge here that I don't know how to solve. I'm trying to create HTML buttons from an Image. This image here is the example I am using. How can I split up all the trapezoids into separate buttons that register separately when tapped on the corresponding regions. I would assume I need to specify some kind of boundary for each trapezoid but I don't know how you would do that for a decently complex shape like this.
[image: Example image]

Comment: How about SVG? And using javascript eventlisting.

Comment: I would vector trace the image and turn it to a SVG. Then attach the proper events in the DOM.

Comment: http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ you could also use clip path however this works in a limited amount of browsers. you could clip the shape of the a element

Comment: map, svg or canvas

Answer (score 2):

Use the HTML `<map>` element to create an **[image map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map)** from the image. Image maps allow you to map out shapes (circles, rectangles and irregular polygonal) from coordinates you provide and these shapes become clickable with their own `href`s. You are also able to get the x,y coordinates during the click event.

There are a variety of free tools on the Internet to generate the coordinates and the overall code.